# How can I get an instance of the MSTest V2 TestContext in the TestCleanup method?

Tags: mstest, testcontext

I'm migrating an existing codebase to MSTest V2 and running into a problem with the `TestContext` in the `TestCleanup` method.

In MSTest V1 the `TestContext` class was static but in V2 it is an instance.  I tried to add a parameter to the `TestCleanup` method, but then I get this message:

> The method must be non-static, public, does not return a value and should not take any parameter.

Ultimately I want to know the name of the test that is being cleaned up and it's test outcome.  If it is not possible to get the `TestContext`, is there any other way to get to that information in the cleanup context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since TestCleanup method and TestContext are not static, then you can just use TestContext inside TestCleanup method without any parameters. Here is an example:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MyNamespace.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void MyTestCleanup()
        {
            TestContext.WriteLine($"Test Cleanup for {TestContext.TestName}");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void MyTestMethod1() { }

        [TestMethod]
        public void MyTestMethod2() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick answer!  I didn't realize that the framework would initialize that variable for me.